# Ec2 public DNS and address net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in browser

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am doing a code based load balancing i.e. on first request to the main server, it returns an address, to which the browser will open a persistent conncection using (wss) websocket. But, due to compatability with my mobile app, i'm returning a public DNS of aws instance, Ex: ec2-35-154-101-63.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com which works fine in the mobile app. The browser however is refusing the connection because the address of websocket is not matching the parent domain. Are there any options to fix this other than using a Wesocket address from the same domain.

Edit:  I had no choice rather than return a subdomain address for the websocket connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are connecting to a URL that does not match the name in the SSL certificate.

You have two choices, either map the domain name to the instance or (not recommended) issue a certificate that matches the URL that you are using (ec2-35-154-101-63.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com)

The correct approach is to specify the A address (IP address) in your DNS server for the EC2 instance so that requests for your_domain_name resolve correctly and then USE that URL and not the EC2 instance DNS name. You cannot specify the AWS URL for https as the SSL certificate was not issued to that identity.